# Canvas & Color-Thief image index size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, color-thief

I'm using [`color-thief`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color-thief) to analyze the colors of images. I'm using a canvas and `getImageData`, I'm getting the following error message in the console:

```
Error: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount
CanvasImage.prototype.getImageData@http://localhost:3000/js/color-thief.js:51:12
ColorThief.prototype.getPalette@http://localhost:3000/js/color-thief.js:109:22
ColorThief.prototype.getColor@http://localhost:3000/js/color-thief.js:75:25
colorController/this.getColors@http://localhost:3000/js/ang.js:20:22
```

I'm not sure if this is a canvas issue coming from image pixel size or if it's some bug in another library (I'm also using AngularJS) but I'm stuck and not sure what I can do.

I think there is an issue with pixel count being 0, when I add the `console.log` line to the following code inside color-thief.js then I get "0 0" for some images.

Crucial point --> the `image.width` and `image.height` show 0 only for SOME images, while the rest it shows ratios that make sense like 1280 922 or 2000 1333.

```
var CanvasImage = function (image) {
    this.canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

    this.width  = this.canvas.width  = image.width;
    this.height = this.canvas.height = image.height;

    console.log(image.width, image.height);

    this.context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
};
```

Any idea why this can happen?

Comment: I have tried to figure out why some images show the INDEX error while others don't.
So far there seems to be no separation between jpg or png or filesize or resolution dimensions... all cases have both images that work and images that don't.

Another strange fact: when cleaning the localhost cache and loading the page, the error occurs for 100% of the images. If refreshed, the site shows errors for some only. This is random, meaning on refresh there could be random changes to what words and what doesn't in terms of the INDEX error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where do you pass image into the function? Are you waiting for the onload event before that happens? an unloaded image will have zero size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to add the `image.addEventListener("load", function() { ... }` to the code to load the image correctly.